# Prevent "Sign Into iCloud" alert from popping up

Tags: ipad, guided-access

I use iPads as a POS for processing transactions.   The iPad is in Guided Access mode, and both Notifications and iCloud drive are turned off.

However, intermittently, a "sign into iCloud" prompt is displayed on the iPad.  Hitting cancel doesn't get rid of it.  The only way to remove it is to enter the Apple ID password.

The idea behind having it locked to Guided Access is so nothing but the POS app is active.  I don't want anyone else to have that password - but the ipad is unusable until that password is entered.  Why is this happening? And is there anyway to disable this notification?

*iPad mini Wi-Fi + Cellular (MM), iOS 8.2, Seen in iOS 8.2 and iOS 8.3*

Comment: I would assume something else is trying to use iCloud. Do you have anything enabled under Settings > iCloud?

Comment: tubedogg, everything is disabled under Settings > iCloud

Comment: Does that screen show you as being signed into iCloud at all? If so, try signing out completely, then do a hard reset (press and hold Home + Sleep until the Apple logo appears), then sign in again.